# Is there a way to have Nokogiri freeze all strings it includes in parsed documents?

Tags: ruby, memory, nokogiri

Parsing large amounts of XML can result in many duplicate strings, such as with element names.

Is there a way to instruct Nokogiri to freeze all strings it returns in the parsed document? This might enable the runtime to coalesce all uses of a given piece of text into a single object in memory, right?

Comment: Which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: 2.7.4 currently, but hope to upgrade to 3.1 some time in the not too distant future.